# how to use variable in mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql

i'm passing variable it show result but no record selected

What am I doing wrong?

```
$starting_date=$_REQUEST['first'];
$ending_date=$_REQUEST['last'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class  
WHERE `date` between DATE_FORMAT( $starting_date,'%Y-%m-%d')  
and DATE_FORMAT($ending_date,'%Y-%m-%d')");
```

Comment: in mysql `date` is in `date` datatype or `datetime`? and echo your `$starting_date` and `$ending_date` variable here.

Comment: date is in timestamp format

Comment: value is coming , checked using echo

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Learning about that will also show you how you erred in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have `datetime` datatype in your mysql table. You should try Something like this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class
        WHERE DATE(`date`) between '$starting_date' and '$ending_date'");
```

if your starting date and ending date is in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD`

**EDIT::JQuery Datepicker:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#starting_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $( "#ending_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

Comment: SQL will interpret `YYYY-MM-DD` as a mathematical problem (hyphen=minus). Variables need to be quoted.

Comment: Use Jquery Datepicker function to format your date.

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone to help me

this funcation change date format

$(function() {
    $( "#starting_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $( "#ending_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});

and this query help me :)

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM class
        WHERE DATE(`date`) between '$starting_date' and '$ending_date'");

Comment: you should accept the answer. You shouldn't post it again.

Comment: i'm new here, i don't new to agree with answer